# Where is the POST tab in Chrome Developer Tools Network?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I’ve recently started using Chrome for development because I’m sick of Firefox’s huge memory footprint. Everything’s going remarkably well, but I just tried to view some posted data in *Developer Tools*, but I can’t seem to find it. I’m confused; I’m sure this used to exist in a `POST` tab, in the Network part of the tools.

[image: screenshot]

I tried looking through the headers, but there’s nothing in there either. Where has it gone‽

Update: In response to an answer below:

> You probably just forgot to click the Record button before submitting
>   the form:

Unfortunately not. There is still no Form Data anywhere to be seen:

[image]

Comment: Isn’t the data right there in your first screenshot? Look at the `Content-Disposition` field; it says **form-data** followed by a `name` field.

Comment: related: ["Chrome: Source of Post Data?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163251/chrome-source-of-post-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that a) there isn't a Post tab anymore, now there is just the Form Data list that is usually present when you use the POST method for an HTML form. I realised that when you use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the  tag, you won't get the Form Data list, but you can still see the data inside the payload list as pointed out by @Synetech.

Answer (score 32):

1. Click the Record button before submitting the form:
   [image: Record Button]
2. Select the correct file (reduce clutter by clicking the category at the bottom)
   [image: Document Selection]
3. Then you can see the POST data:
   [image: POST Data]

Comment: See my edit above - this might be the solution for some people but for me it didn't work. Thanks, though.

Comment: You need to make sure to select the correct file. It looks like you did in the screenshot, but are you sure the data is not associated with something else? You can check the source code to see what file receives the data by looking at the `action` attribute of the `form` tag.

Comment: As you can see, that's the only file. I was definitely selecting that, but still no luck.

Comment: It looks like the data is right under your nose, in the *“payload”*: **Content-Disposition: form-data; name="xUsername…**

Comment: Yes it seems to be in there - though that's not the Post tab or form data list. I now know _why_ it's going that however (see other answer).

Answer (score 3):

For Seam applications or other frameworks that use a POST-Redirect pattern, you might have to use the **Other** category filter instead of the **Documents** filter to see the **Form Data** section.